# Add DropDown without refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Good Evening,

Could one of you suggest a way to add a dropdown box dynamically without refreshing the page? The dropdown box must not be visible at first, it must then become visible later based on a choice made by the user.  However one constraint is it can only be Javascript, Php, and/or html

Answer (score 3):

You can add `display:none` to your dropdown box style and add a link that have `onclick=document.getElemetById('myDropDownBox').style.disply = 'block'` to show the box.

BUUUT... it's best to Google it and learn more about this stuff. There is lots of cool stuff about this out there.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to include the HTML but hidden, then display it via Javascript when appropiate. Need more deatails?

Comment: ...but move it out of the form to make sure it won't be sent on submit, if hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dropdown to the page like normal, only set its css to `display:none`, then when a box is clicked, you can do something like this in javascript:

```
$("#MyBox").click(function(){
    $("#dropdown").show('fast');
});
```

This jquery function will add a smooth transition to show the box

I also agree with @Mohsen

> BUUUT... it's best to Google it and
>   learn more about this stuff. There is
>   lots of cool stuff about this out
>   there.

You might just be on the edge of learning some really neat stuff! Be adventurous and enjoy this stage of the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a useful example.

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden { display:none }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(element, value) {
    switch (element.name) {
        case 'select1':
            switch (value) {
                case '0':
                    document.getElementById('select2').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('select3').style.display = 'none';
                    break;
                case '1':
                    document.getElementById('select2').style.display = 'inline';
                    document.getElementById('select3').style.display = 'none';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    document.getElementById('select2').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('select3').style.display = 'inline';
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
</script>

<form>
    <p id="select1">
        <label>Select 1:
            <select name="select1" onchange="show(this, this.value)">
                <option value="0">First</option>
                <option value="1">Second</option>
                <option value="2">Third</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p id="select2" class="hidden">
        <label>Select 2:
            <select name="select2">
                <option>Option</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p id="select3" class="hidden">
        <label>Select 3:
            <select name="select3">
                <option>Option</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```